# getting error message along with result in go api

Tags: api, go, google-cloud-firestore, go-gin

I have one route in API where I can get users with `roles`. In this route, if I put the name of the user then I will get all the `roles` assigned to him/her. But the problem is that it returns only the first result. If that role is present in another object then it is not getting displayed. So I comment on the `return` line and everything works fine but along with the result, I am getting the error message:`"user not found"` Can you guys please tell me what mistake I am doing?
Thank you.
Route -

```
GET("/users/:username", controllers.GetUserByRole)
```

Controller -

```
func GetUserByRole(c *gin.Context) {
    paramId := c.Param("username")
    .............
    .............
    .............
    var newUsers []models.User
    iter := client.Collection("users").Documents(ctx)

    for {
        doc, err := iter.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to iterate: %v", err)
        }

        var tempUsers models.User
        if err := doc.DataTo(&tempUsers); err != nil {
            break
        }
        newUsers = append(newUsers, tempUsers)
    }

    for _, a := range newUsers {
        for _, element := range a.Roles{
                if element == paramId {
            c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, a)
            return     //if I comment this line line then I geting message `"user not found"` along with results
        }
    }
    }
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"message": "user not found"})
}
```

URL: `http://localhost:3000/users/Analyst`
Response Should be:

```
  {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Leanne Graham",
     "username": "Bret",
     "roles": ["Developer", "Analyst"],
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Clementine Bauch",
    "username": "Samantha",
    "roles": ["Manger", "Analyst"],
  }
```

but I am getting like this (only the first matching one):

```
  {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Leanne Graham",
     "username": "Bret",
     "roles": ["Developer", "Analyst"],
  }
```

If I comment the `return` line then response is (desired result + error message):

```
  {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Leanne Graham",
     "username": "Bret",
     "roles": ["Developer", "Analyst"],
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Clementine Bauch",
    "username": "Samantha",
    "roles": ["Manger", "Analyst"],
  }{
    "message": "album not found"
}
```

Complete API response -

```
[
  {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Leanne Graham",
     "username": "Bret",
     "roles": ["Developer", "Analyst"],
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "roles": ["Assistant"],,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Clementine Bauch",
    "username": "Samantha",
    "roles": ["Manger", "Analyst"],
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
var userList []models.User
for _, a := range newUsers {
    for _, element := range a.AssignedTo {
        if element == paramId {
            userList = append(userList, a)
        }
    }
}
if len(userList) == 0 {
     c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"message": "user not found"})
     return
}

c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, userList)
```

Comment: fixed typo error

Comment: Nope. It is not working for me

Comment: can you tell me what you are getting with the above code implementation?

Comment: I am getting error as ```no result values expected``` on both return statements

Comment: just remove the return keyword from the last line. It works fine. Instead ```return c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, userList)``` do this ```c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, userList)```

Comment: You are right in your function signature there is no return parameter there. I have added my answer. you can accept the answer if it is working for you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your return statement is inside your for loop, so it find the first value and immediately returns. Your function doesn't return when you comment it out so it completes successfully and then prints the error message. Move the return statement outside both for loops and it should be fine. Also, add logic for sending the error message by having an errorflag. The alternative solution from Manjeet Thakur is also recommended.

```
func GetUserByRole(c *gin.Context) {
    paramId := c.Param("username")
    .............
    .............
    .............
    var newUsers []models.User
    iter := client.Collection("users").Documents(ctx)
 
    for {
        doc, err := iter.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to iterate: %v", err)
        }
 
        var tempUsers models.User
        if err := doc.DataTo(&tempUsers); err != nil {
            break
        }
        newUsers = append(newUsers, tempUsers)
    }
    var errorflag := 1
    for _, a := range newUsers {
        for _, element := range a.AssignedTo {
                if element == paramId {
            c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, a)
            errorflag := 0
                 //if I comment this line line then I geting message `"user not found"` along with results
        }
    }
    }
    if errorflag{
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"message": "user not found"})
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: I have written like this but getting error - 
```
for _, a := range newUsers {
        for _, element := range a.AssignedTo {
                if element == paramId {
            c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, a)
        }
        return    //error-the surrounding loop is unconditionally terminated
    }
    }
    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"message": "user not found"})
```

Comment: My bad, your return statements needs to be outside of your inner and outer for loop, currently it is inside the outer for loop, inside the inner for loop, and inside the if block.

Also, your error message will never be sent this way, as it simply loops through the users and sends them if they match the request, then your function returns. What you need to do is check if there are no users matching the request, and do that error message if true. This is my understanding of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have placed the return statement at every possible line but it is not working. So it will be good and easy to understand for me if you write the code snippet in answer, if possible.

Comment: I've edited it to show you what I mean.

Comment: Also check Manjeet Thakur's answer above, though I believe the last line should be `return c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, userList)`

Comment: After moving the return statement outside both for loops. it is giving me error on next line - `unreacheable code`.

Comment: If possible, you can provide new approach for writing this handler. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240433/discussion-between-exertustfm-and-rocco).